# ListViewItem EventTrigger not firing WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have ListView with defined in xaml ListViewItems. I'm trying to bind command to LisdtViewItem on PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown click event via Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf but it doesn't work.

**Xaml code:**

```
                    <ListView x:Name="SideMenu"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                              BorderThickness="0 0 1 0"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItem}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageAddress}" Style="{StaticResource MenuIcon}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListViewItem IsSelected="True">
                            <Image Source="../Icons/TestPlan.png" Style="{StaticResource MenuIcon}"/>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestingCommand}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </ListViewItem>
```

**ViewModelCode:**

```
    public sealed class SideMenuControlViewModel
    {
        public ICommand GetOddsCommand { get; set; }

        public SideMenuControlViewModel()
        {
            GetOddsCommand = new RelayCommand(o => GetOdds());
        }

        public ICommand TestingCommand
        {
            get => new RelayCommand((s) => Test()); 
        }

        private void GetOdds()
        {

        }

        private void Test()
        {
            int a = 5;
            int b = a + a;
        }
    }
```

Also, I tried to add event trigger inside image and border but this also didn't help...

Comment: In your question you write "on left mous click", but your trigger fires on `MouseDoubleClick`. So for double click it should work.

Comment: @thatguy I changed on PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown in question. Thank you. I also tried with MouseDoubleClick event but it didn't work..

Comment: Shouldn’t EventTriggers use “RoutedEvents”? Never done it through “EvenName”.

Comment: @TomášBuchta I don't see RoutedEvent property in xaml. Maybe this is because I'm using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors EventTrigger...

Comment: If you need an immediate working solution, this should do the trick without need for triggers or Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors : <ListViewItem.InputBindings> and inside <MouseBinding MouseAction=“LeftClick” Command={Binding TestingCommand}”/> ... if this does not work, there can be a problem with binding / data context as well. Can’t help much more, sorry.

Comment: @TomášBuchta I tried this now and it didn't work. Also I tried to specify like that <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ElementName=SideMenu, Path=DataContext.TestingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" /> with specifying DataContext but that didn't work too. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I used ICommand not from System.Windows.Input and just copied it from tutorial...
I just changed my RelayCommand class inheritance and command binding started work as usual

```
    public sealed class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action _action;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = (sender, e) => { };

        public RelayCommand(Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
```